# Trouble with Ninja Forms and Mandrill

Tags: wordpress, mandrill

I'm having a website where a ninja form is placed. According to ninja forms it should work perfectly with wpMandrill plugin.

I have both installed and configured. Mandrill is working fine. Without ninja forms mails are successfully sent. I've also set up DNS records for mandrill so it sends on behalf of.

But I'm still not receiving any mails through ninja forms. I have actually no idea what the problem could be.

Has anyone any idea what this problem could be?

Thanks! :)

Sources:
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmandrill/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and stumbled upon your question while Googling for an answer. I tried the same thing you did with Mandrill - No use.

Ultimately, I ended up installing an SMTP plugin called "[Postman SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/)" and configured it with a Gmail account I created just for this purpose.

The configuration was quite a few steps, but it resulted in those pesky ninja emails FINALLY sending correctly.

Hope this helps!